# Using Kryo to serialize a Spark mllib model

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, kryo

I want to serialize a model which is generate from ML lib Classifacation Tree,
A model is construct by a Node and a Algo, Node seems serializable
Can we just serialize a whole model to disk and read from another class to get the model back?

Thanks